# Addin to add XML comments for private variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-addins, xml-comments

Just like Ghostdoc is there any add-in for Visual Studio 2008 that can automatically add XML comments for private variables, as Ghostdoc and few others doesn't support private variables.

Comment: Isn't it better to place your cursor right above your variable (or method, namespace or class) and just hit three slashes [///] after each other, getting your XML-comment template, and type in by yourself what its used for?

Answer (score 0):

[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) does support XML comments for private variables.  I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Ghostdoc supports private variables just fine.  Ctrl-Shift-D creates

```
/// <summary>
///
/// </summary>
private readonly string attachmentName;
```

And you just fill in the blank within the summary with what that variable is for.